# Outlook Rest API bug in findmeetingtimes

Tags: c#, outlook, office365, office365api

I encountered an issue with following Outlook Rest API :

outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/findmeetingtimes

In particular I found that API works only if requested timeslot is set to o'Clock or Half-Past the requested time.

For example, if I send following request :

```
{
"Attendees": [],
"TimeConstraint": {
"ActivityDomain": "Unrestricted",
"Timeslots": [{
"Start": {
"DateTime": "2032-07-10T07:45:00",
"TimeZone": "UTC"
},
"End": {
"DateTime": "2032-07-10T08:45:00",
"TimeZone": "UTC"
}
}]
},
"MeetingDuration": "PT1H",
"MaxCandidates": 100
}
```

API returns following RESPONSE:

```
{
    "EmptySuggestionsReason": "OrganizerUnavailable",
    "MeetingTimeSuggestions": []
}
```

Instead using the following request :

```
{
"Attendees": [],
"TimeConstraint": {
"ActivityDomain": "Unrestricted",
"Timeslots": [{
"Start": {
"DateTime": "2032-07-10T07:30:00",
"TimeZone": "UTC"
},
"End": {
"DateTime": "2032-07-10T08:30:00",
"TimeZone": "UTC"
}
}]
},
"MeetingDuration": "PT1H",
"MaxCandidates": 100
}
```

The RESPONSE comes correctly :

```
{
    "EmptySuggestionsReason": "",
    "MeetingTimeSuggestions": [
        {
            "Confidence": 100,
            "OrganizerAvailability": "Free",
            "MeetingTimeSlot": {
                "Start": {
                    "DateTime": "2032-07-10T07:30:00.0000000",
                    "TimeZone": "UTC"
                },
                "End": {
                    "DateTime": "2032-07-10T08:30:00.0000000",
                    "TimeZone": "UTC"
                }
            },
            "AttendeeAvailability": [],
            "Locations": [
                {
                    "DisplayName": "Sala Break A",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": ""
                },
                {
                    "DisplayName": "Milano, MI, Italia",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "",
                    "LocationUri": "",
                    "Address": {
                        "Type": "Home",
                        "Street": "undefined, undefined",
                        "City": "Milano",
                        "State": "Italia",
                        "CountryOrRegion": "MI",
                        "PostalCode": ""
                    },
                    "Coordinates": {
                        "Latitude": 45.4654219,
                        "Longitude": 9.18592430000001
                    }
                },
                {
                    "DisplayName": "Sala Break",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": ""
                },
                {
                    "DisplayName": "napoli",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": ""
                },
                {
                    "DisplayName": "Napoli",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "",
                    "LocationUri": "https://www.bingapis.com/api/v6/geoentities/7216548829858889729",
                    "Address": {
                        "Type": "Home",
                        "Street": "",
                        "City": "Napoli",
                        "State": "Campania",
                        "CountryOrRegion": "Italia",
                        "PostalCode": ""
                    },
                    "Coordinates": {
                        "Latitude": 40.8401,
                        "Longitude": 14.2523
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

By my opinion this is a Bug.

Is there any possibility that the same will be fixed?
Does anyone know a valid Work Around to not suffer this issue?

Comment: Would you be able too make the indentation of the working and non-working inputs consistent (to make comparisons between them easier)?

Comment: @mjwills is the indentation ok ?

Comment: Much better, ta.